# How to give port number for docker container at run time?

Tags: scala, rest, docker, containers, akka-http

I have written one Scala and Akka HTTP based REST API and created Dockerfile to create Docker image for this API. My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_TOOL_CHAIN
COPY pom.xml /tmp/parent/
COPY data-catalogue/pom.xml /tmp/parent/data-catalogue/
COPY data-catalogue/src /tmp/parent/data-catalogue/src/
WORKDIR /tmp/parent/data-catalogue/
RUN mvn package

FROM java:openjdk-8
COPY --from=MAVEN_TOOL_CHAIN /tmp/parent/data-catalogue/target/data-catalogue-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/data-catalogue.jar

COPY data-catalogue/src/main/resources/logback.xml /opt/logback.xml

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dlogging.config=/opt/logback.xml", "-jar", "/opt/data-catalogue.jar", "prod"]
CMD ["8080"]
```

Everything is good so far. I can run one container using this image.

Now requirement is to run two containers using this image on same Docker host. I have modified REST APIs main class such that it will take port number on which it has to run as an command line argument. If command line argument is not provided then it will listen for requests on 8080 port.

I would like to know how do I provide command line parameter to my REST API while starting container?

For example:

1. First instance of REST API should start/run on port 5555 so this 5555 argument should reach main class of REST API
2. Second instance of REST API should start/run on port 1111 so this 5555 argument should reach main class of REST API

I have tried to use `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` for this but my command line argument simply does not reach main class and REST API starts on 8080 port only.

Comment: why not use `ARG` ?

Comment: I am fairly new to Docker so don't know about this ARG. will try it and let you know. Thanks

Comment: I added an example for you

Comment: You mean your container ports should be 5555 and 1111?  Do you need to map them to host to?

Comment: @deosha
 Yes. host should forward requests on 5555 to containers 5555 port AND my AKKA REST API should start listening on 5555 port as well

Comment: why don't you put `expose 5555` just above `cmd`. Your `cmd` is irrelevant here because `8080` is not a command.

Comment: because 5555 is just an example. I should be able to pass any port number to the container and underlying REST API and API should start using that port number itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Docker PORT mapping** is your answer.

Dockerizing your API is exactly the opposite to provide your API with the port you want to run it on everytime. That's exactly what you don't want to do when going the Docker way.

Your API should be able to attend to your requests through whichever port you decide to `EXPOSE` on your docker image, and then, at run time, you just need to map any port you wish from your host to the inner port of your API (which, inside its container, will be attending to the same "internal" port always.

So.. how does it look like?

```
docker run -d --name api-1 -p 5555:8080 my/api
```

and then...

```
docker run -d --name api-2 -p 1111:8080 my/api
```

Now both instances are running on your host, and you're able to hit both of them, each with a different host port (even when internally they're using the same port number)

Comment: More on this _binding_ / _port-publish_ feature [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/) and some more guidelines on basic docker container networking [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)
 Enjoy ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly I was looking for. Somehow I was assuming that two docker containers won't be able to listen to same port. Port mapping is the key to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Through Environment Variables

In Dockerfile:

```
ENV PORT 8080
```

You can override the above `env` on the cmd by passing `-e` for e.g.

```
docker run -d my_image -e "PORT=5555"
```

Consume the `env` in your application code

So for e.g. if you don't provide env on the cmd, your application code will receive `8080` as PORT value. If you do override the env on cmd, your application code will receive `5555` as PORT value

Answer (score 2):

you can set ARG to your container:

```
ARG MYPORT
```

then export it like:

```
CMD [ $MYPORT ]
```

then start your docker like this:

```
export MYPORT=5000 ; docker run ....
```

Comment: I think you can read the valur from SYS ENV or replace it when building the Image using `sed`

Comment: Okay. I think reading from SYS ENV is fine but adding it during build wont help because I don't want to create separate containers just for using different ports.